# Limiting Code Deploy revisions with max_revisions value is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-code-deploy

I am attempting to limit the quantity of successful code deploy revisions that are preserved on the EC2 instances by editing the `codedeployagent.yml` file’s `max_revisions` value.  I have currently set the value to `:max_revisions: 2`.

I believe that the issue I am having is due to the method that I am setting the file value.  I am attempting to set the value by deploying it with the code deploy package.  To do this I have created a custom `codedeployagent.yml` file locally at the following location:

`etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml`

In my `appspec.yml` file I am specifying the installation location of this file by the following lines:

```
- source: etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
     destination: /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf
```

I have found that this errors out when I attempt to deploy due to the script already being in place.  To work around this, I have added a script that hooks on `BeforeInstall` with my `appspec.yml` that will remove the script prior to installing the package:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
```

Okay, so after this I have `ssh`’d into the server and sure enough, the `:max_revisions: 2` value is set as expected.  Unfortunately, in practice I am seeing many more revisions than just two being preserved on the `ec2` instances.

So, to go back to the beginning of my question here… Clearly this workaround is not the best way to update the `codedeployagent.yml` file.  I should add that I am deploying to an auto scaling group, so this needs to be a solution that can live in the deployment scripts or cloud formation templates rather than just logging in and hardcoding the value.  With all this info, what am I missing here?  How can I properly limit the revisions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you restart the agent after updating the config file? Any new configurations won't work until you restart the agent.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me and I have a server restart that is triggered during the `ApplicationStart` hook for code deploy that runs `sudo service httpd restart`.  Do you think that I need this at a different hook for the config file change?

Comment: I have added the following line to the `ApplicationStart` hook:  `sudo service codedeploy-agent restart` I also changed `:max_revisions: 1`.  After deploying another time, I checked the `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/12...83/` directory and there are two successful revision packages there.  Shouldn't it just be one?

Comment: At long last... I realize that I did not have a correct understanding of the `max_revisions` value.  When set to 1 it actually retains 2.  It keeps one for the current deployment and then 1 for the retained previous deployment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try one of below approaches.

1. Take an AMI of an instance where you already modified `max_revisions` to `2` and update ASG's Launch configuration with this AMI, so that scale out instance will also have this config.
2. Add this config in your userdata section while creating launch configuration
   Command to add in userdata section

   ```
     "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [ 
     "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
     "# Delete last line and add new line \n",
     "sed '$ d' /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml > /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/temp.yml\n",
     "echo ':max_revisions: 2' >> /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/temp.yml\n",
     "rm -f /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml\n",
     "mv /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/temp.yml /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml\n",
     "service codedeploy-agent restart\n"
     ]]}}
   ```

As per [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-agent-configuration.html), max_revisions applies for applications per deployment group. So it keeps only 2 revisions under `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/<deployment_group_id>/`. If ASG is associated with multiple applications, codedeploy will store 2 revisions of each application in its deployment_group_id directory.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I would rather not take an AMI due to several reasons.  With this being the case, it sounds like the second option would be a better solution.  Can you provide a sample script on how I could update the `max_revisions` in the userdata section of my could formation template?

Comment: Done! Edited in answer.

Comment: I have attempted this update to my cloud formation template and I am getting the following error `Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement`.  I have attempted adjusting the `MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent` to zero, but for some odd reason this is still the error message.

Comment: As @binbinlu suggested, added codedeploy-agent restart after config change. Can you try with that change ?

Comment: I have attempted `sudo service codedeploy-agent restart` at `ApplicationStart` hook, but I am still seeing revisions in excess of the `max-revisions` value.  More details in @binbinlu's answer.  Am I missing the point of the `max_revisions` parameter?  Shouldn't it eliminate any records beyond that value?

Comment: thanks for your assistance.  I finally got it working with the restart and a better understanding of how code deploy retains the deployments.